# Flutter - Continuous tracking of the position of a Draggable widget

Tags: flutter

I want to build a drag'n'drop scenario using the Draggable and DragTarget Flutter widgets. So far so good.

Now additionally I need to track/log the position of the Feedback widget while the user is dragging so in the end I have a list of positions and their corresponding time.

Comming from the game development industry I'd do such things using an update loop but obviously Flutter works differently and the Draggable widget seems to only have callbacks for *drag start*, *canceled*, *end* and *completed* but not something like 'feedbackWidgetHasMoved' or so.

So, what are the possible approaches to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to use a `GestureDetector` instead. It's a bit more work, but achieves what you need using its properties, specifically the `onLongPressMoveUpdate` which gives you local and global offsets of the widget.

```
GestureDetector(
  child: SomeWidget(),
  onLongPress: (details) => print('long press started'),
  onLongPressMoveUpdate: (details) => {
    print('----- time: ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
    print(details.globalPosition);
    print(details.localPosition);
    print(details.offsetFromOrigin);
    print(details.localOffsetFromOrigin);
  }
)
```